# Understanding auto decrement in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, decrement

I am new to Java. I'm trying to run while loop and if condition inside while loop.
There is decrement in the middle of while loop. 
Can I put the decrement (x=x-1) at the end? What does it mean if i put it in the middle and if I put it at the end?
Please explain me the difference.

```
public class shuffle1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 3;

        while (x > 0) {
            if (x > 2) {
                System.out.print("a");
            }

            x = x - 1;

            System.out.print("-");

            if (x == 2) {
                System.out.print("b c");
            }

            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.print("d");
                x = x - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? Why don't you try to put the decrement at the end of the loop, and run the code to see what the output is?

Comment: As you are putting it in the middle. The last 2 if block in the while loop will evaluate based on the updated value of x.

Comment: There is no 'auto decrement' here.

Comment: i was output a-b c-d. Can i get the same result if i put the decrement at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you put x=x-1 in the middle, two of your statements inside while loop will be executed in single iteration i.e a-b c would be printed in single iteration. When you put it in the end a-b c would be printed in two iterations of the loop. So you are saving one iteration with this approach. Cleaner way to write the same code,
  int x = 3;

```
do {
    if (x > 2) {
        System.out.print("a");
    }

    System.out.print("-");

    if (x == 2) {
        System.out.print("b c");
    }

    if (x == 1) {
        System.out.print("d");
    }
}while (0 < --x);
```

Comment: --x will first decrease the value and then compare with 0. x++ will compare with zero then decrease the value. Just print the value of x inside loop, you will be able to figure out the difference